# How to kill php process which use thread from terminal mac osx

Tags: php, macos, terminal, pthreads

I have run php script in terminal

> php test.php

I always kill executing of the script by 'ctrl+c' or

> kill pid

But now this script doesn't kill. I think it's because I use **Thread** in my script.

Does anyone know how I can stop executing of the script?

**UPD**
code of the php script

```
class TestThread extends Thread {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function run() {
        while(true) {
            // Do something
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
}

$thread = new TestThread();
$thread->start();
```

Comment: `kill -9 <pid>`.  This sends a sigkill, but without the -9 it sends a sigterm, which may not be enough.

Comment: If I try this on Debian I can kill the script with `ctrl+c` or `SIGTERM`. What's different on OS X?